# Как сделать нормальную валидацию в Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

В документации по Symfony предлагают два способа: писать аннотации к модели, что не подходит, так как если придут данные без какого то поля, то до валидации не дойдет и придется вручную проверять все поля, что делает такой способ бессмысленным, и создавать форму отдельным файлом и подставлять в шаблон, что также неудобно.

Comment: Для этого как раз есть **NotBlank**

Comment: Можно воспользоваться сторонними либами типа https://github.com/franzose/kontrolio